# Need to add year, make, model to php

Tags: php, html

I have a quote request page and it is handled by php.  This is what I have so far..

```
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;


**---THIS IS WHERE I WANT YEAR, MAKE, AND MODEL TO BE DISPLAYED AND NOT SIDE BY SIDE--- 
     Vehicle Year: using $year
     Vehicle Make: using $make
     Vehicle Model: using $model**

     $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";
     if ($phone) $e_reply .= " or via phone $phone.";        

     $msg = wordwrap($e_body . $e_content . $e_reply,70);
```

If you have any good input let me know.  I don't use php that much or else I could probably knock this out pretty easily.

Comment: You don't actually ask a question here. Treat the title as a summary, but ask the full question in the question text.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What does it do so far? What problems do you have? Please answer these questions and we will be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving the content through a contact form using the `$_POST` array you can do something like this:

```
$year = $_POST["year"];
$make = $_POST["make"];
$model = $_POST["model"];
```

Then add it to the rest of your content:

```
$e_content. = "Year: " . $year . "Make: " . $make . "Model: " . $model;
```

Comment: Thanks for actually responding instead of marking me down like the rest of the people.  I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: That worked.  How do you do line breaks in php?  To make Year Make and Model look like a vertical display?

Comment: You can use `"\n"` or `<br>`. So, `"Year: " . $year . "\n"` Would give you a line break between Year and make.

Comment: Ok that is all I need.  Thank you!